# RTOS KEIL to GCC conversion

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32, freertos

I have a FreeRTOS code under KEIL compiler and all is OK. When I convert the same code to CooCox under GCC, where are only changes in asm code in port.c etc. It does not work. It is looping in debug in function `xPortStartScheduler()` where `prvPortStartFirstTask()` go to `Svc_Handler` and again to `xPortStartScheduler()` etc. I think that problem can be somewhere in vectors or startup file.

*In CooCox I can't find heap and stack initialization instead of Keil sturtup.*

Someone has an idea?

Comment: Problem was solved by rewriting vector table of imported CooCox sturtup  where "vPortSVCHandler" was not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by rewriting vector table of imported CooCox sturtup where "vPortSVCHandler" was not defined. – Hw-dev Cz

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to freeRTOS but you may find the startup file in CooCox by adding CMSIS boot component to the project. View->Repository and add CMSIS boot component to visualize the startup file in cmsis_boot/startup directory.

Comment: Yes I know that, but when I use original CooCox startup file then code ends with Hard_Fault_Handler error. Since it I'm using rewrited assembler code from KEIL for GCC.